# Array Match & Add Values to First array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays one with conversion_offer_id, conversions & payout. Now i want to match it with another array and add all the values of first array to second array and if not then add values of conversion & payout as 0.

Array 1 ($conversions)

```
[
{
"conversion_offer_id": 90,
"conversions": 15,
"payout": 225
},
{
"conversion_offer_id": 196,
"conversions": 1,
"payout": 120
},
{
"conversion_offer_id": 720,
"conversions": 53,
"payout": 1590
}
]
```

Array 2 ($clkcs)

```
[
{
"clicks": 142,
"offer_currency": 45,
"click_offer_id": 90,
"click_affiliate_id": 9106,
"offer_name": "BKS",
"offer_id": 90,
"currency_symbol": "₹"
},
{
"clicks": 8,
"offer_currency": 45,
"click_offer_id": 196,
"click_affiliate_id": 9106,
"offer_name": "FFU",
"offer_id": 196,
"currency_symbol": "₹"
},
{
"clicks": 1,
"offer_currency": 45,
"click_offer_id": 246,
"click_affiliate_id": 9106,
"offer_name": "GFT",
"offer_id": 246,
"currency_symbol": "₹"
},
{
"clicks": 1,
"offer_currency": 45,
"click_offer_id": 334,
"click_affiliate_id": 9106,
"offer_name": "JPR",
"offer_id": 334,
"currency_symbol": "₹"
},
{
"clicks": 1,
"offer_currency": 45,
"click_offer_id": 622,
"click_affiliate_id": 9106,
"offer_name": "TWS",
"offer_id": 622,
"currency_symbol": "₹"
},
{
"clicks": 1197,
"offer_currency": 45,
"click_offer_id": 720,
"click_affiliate_id": 9106,
"offer_name": "KPS",
"offer_id": 720,
"currency_symbol": "₹"
}
]
```

My Logic to achieve

```
foreach($clkcs as $k=>$key){
            foreach($conversions as $ckey){
                if($key['click_offer_id']==$ckey['conversion_offer_id']){

                    $clkcs[$k]['offer_id']=$ckey['conversion_offer_id'];

                    $clkcs[$k]['conversions']=$ckey['conversions'];
                    $clkcs[$k]['payout']=$ckey['payout'];

                }else{
                    $clkcs[$k]['conversions']='0';
                    $clkcs[$k]['payout']='0';

                }
            }

        }
```

Conversions & payout for only last matching values are populating fine. For rest of them its 0.

But it should also add the conversion & payout for offer ID 90 & 196.

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need stop second foreach after success filling of $clkcs

```
foreach($clkcs as $k=>$key){
    $clkcs[$k]['conversions']='0';
    $clkcs[$k]['payout']='0';

    foreach($conversions as $ckey){
        if($key['click_offer_id']==$ckey['conversion_offer_id']){
            $clkcs[$k]['offer_id']=$ckey['conversion_offer_id'];

            $clkcs[$k]['conversions']=$ckey['conversions'];
            $clkcs[$k]['payout']=$ckey['payout'];

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You repopulate array every time you foreach $clkcs.

So after setting right conversations for ID 90 in first run in next one you set conversions = 0 and payout = 0 for ID 90 again.

Now you should find right way to do it :)

If you like to make it faster and easier (and conversion_offer_id is unique) add it as $conversions[conversion_offer_id] and iterate only one array.

Comment: Id depends what your script needs are.
If only one match is possible you can do it very fast by checking if 'conversions' is set already (!=0) and not reporulate it again.